# jlink: Application jars are not created in /bin folder

Tags: java, jlink, java-12

I am executing below command to create an image.

```
jlink --module-path jars/:$JAVA_HOME/jmods --add-modules app.main,app.interfaces.impl,app.interfaces.otherimpl --output image
```

'app.main' module contains main class.

'app.interfaces.impl' and 'app.interfaces.otherimpl' are modules that implement interfaces in 'app.interfaces' module.

When I create the image using jlink command it creates java and keytool commands in bin folder, but no modules are copied.

```
$tree
.
├── image
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── java
│   │   └── keytool
```

But when I execute 'java --list-modules', it is listing all the modules.

```
$./image/bin/java --list-modules
app.interfaces
app.interfaces.impl
app.interfaces.otherimpl
app.main
java.base@12.0.1
$
```

How can I run the main class from app.main module? where exactly the modules copied?

Comment: You might have created the modules `app.main`, `app.interfaces.impl` and `app.interfaces.otherimpl` in `/JAVA_HOME/jmods` or `jars/` folder itself. Apart from that try executing `java --module-path jars/:$JAVA_HOME/jmods -m app.main/app.main.MainClass`

Comment: Hi Naman, Thanks for the answer, I can run the jar file from the command provided by you. But actually I want to create an image, how can i do that?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the`-- launcher` option. Other than that, you already have an image, don't you?

Comment: What do you think, is the purpose of [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm)? “*You can use the jlink tool to assemble and optimize a set of modules and their dependencies into a custom runtime image*” If you want to copy the unoptimized zip files, you can use the copy command of your operating system. And when `/image/bin/java --list-modules` shows your module, you can run it with `/image/bin/java -m app.main`, if the module has declared a mainclass or `/image/bin/java -m app.main/actual.mainclass` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I run the main class from app.main module?

Apart from that to execute the main class, you can use the command line:

```
/image/bin/java -m app.main/app.main.MainClass
```

or use the `--launcher` option to create a launch script in the bin directory, e.g.

```
--launcher app=app.main/app.main.MainClass
```

which create "app" in the bin directory.

Comment: @Holger from the question *`$./image/bin/java --list-modules`*, I had assumed that the `java` used here was the same under the [image created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601687/jlink-application-jars-are-not-created-in-bin-folder/56602491?noredirect=1#comment99780929_56601687). Correct, the module path shouldn't be required either as the `--list-modules` already justify the presence of the required modules in the image.

Comment: @Naman with -m option i can able to run the application. I thought when i create an image, it copies all the specified and depenedent modules. Since './image/bin/java --list-modules' listing all the avaialble modules in my image, i can confirm that these modules are part of my image. Is this modules are now part of java launcher or copied somewhere in the image?

Comment: @HariKrishna They are now a part of the image you've created. You can possibly list all the files in your `/image` folder and validate its size as well as compared to the JDK modules.

Comment: @HariKrishna In addition to the current image, `--launcher` and list of complete files one could see are nicely [detailed here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-9-changes/jlink.html).